# aurioTouch not playing back

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-audio, audiounit

I just downloaded and tried this one on the iPad.  The mic is working since I can see the graphics displayed in response to voices.  But there was no playback from the speaker.  Yes, I have tried both mute button on and off.   Any hint as to what happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember there is some problem with pass-thru in that application, when I looked at it a few months back.

Try removing the DC filter.

I think it is a horrible piece of code, so forgive me for not digging into it.

I can't remember if it is just a simulator bug or whether it also hits the device.

Comment: According to aurioTouch's revision history on Apple website, that issue seemed to have been fixed with the current version.

I have also tried to comment out these lines (197-199) in the aurioTouchAppDelegate.mm. But it did not fix the problem.  

// // Remove DC component
// for(UInt32 i = 0; i < ioData->mNumberBuffers; ++i)
//  THIS->dcFilter[i].InplaceFilter((SInt32*)(ioData->mBuffers[i].mData), inNumberFrames, 1);

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? There is not much benefit in using that code for anything.  For the purposes of learning, it is horrible code.

Comment: In another Apple's example called Wavy.  It takes audio from the mic and plot a waveform on the screen.  I am trying to learn how to get output from the mic and playback.  In this Wavy example, there is a captureOutput delegate method that can return the CMSampleBufferRef...  I was thinking to feed this sampleBuffer into some type of playback mehod.

Can it be done this way?